# how to find out R library location in Mac OSX?

Tags: r, macos

On linux it's usually `$HOME/R/...`, where is it on a Mac?

I tried something like `locate Rcpp`, but didn't get any useful info.

R is installed through homebrew, and OSX version is 10.9 (mavericks).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With `.Library` you get your default library location
With `.libPaths("your/path")` you can also get/set you library trees (see `?.libPaths`)
and with `getwd()` resp. `setwd("your/path")` you get/set your working-directory

Comment: Very nice. I got this: `[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Resources/library"`

Comment: @qed You probably installed it with homebrew.

Answer (score 11):

You may use the function [`find.package`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/find.package.html) to find the paths to one or more packages.

Example (finding the path of the R library `rj`):

```
> find.package('rj')
[1] "\\\\nas/users/dernoncourt/Documents/dernoncourt/R/win-library/3.4/rj"
```

Alternatively you may use `packageDescription`.  For example:

```
> packageDescription("rj")
Encoding: UTF-8
Package: rj
Version: 2.1.0-13
Title: RJ - R Package for high-level Java-R library RJ
Author: Stephan Wahlbrink, Tobias Verbeke, low-level R binding based on the JRI library by Simon Urbanek
Maintainer: Stephan Wahlbrink <stephan.wahlbrink@walware.de>
Depends: R (>= 2.11.0)
Suggests: rj.gd
SystemRequirements: java
Description: Server implementation and R functions for the high-level Java-R library RJ.  The package also includes callback functions for StatET.  It is shipped with an adapted version of the JRI library.  The package can be used only when R was loaded via RJ.
License: LGPL (== 2.1)
URL: http://www.walware.de/goto/opensource
NeedsCompilation: yes
Packaged: 2017-05-10 08:22:44 UTC; build
Built: R 3.4.0; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2017-05-10 08:25:27 UTC; windows

-- File: \\nas/users/dernoncourt/Documents/dernoncourt/R/win-library/3.4/rj/Meta/package.rds
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you look at `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library`

Comment: If it was installed by the default package system, it should have been /.../R.framework//Versions/2.15/Resources/library or substituting 3.0 or Current for the 2.15,