# RStudio Error: "C stack usage is too close to the limit" at R startup

Tags: r

Every time I open a new session in RStudio, I see the following error message (before I even run any of my code):

> Error: C stack usage  7969360 is too close to the limit

I don't see this error when I open an R Console without RStudio.

Any advice on how to fix this?

In case it is helpful, here is some info:

- R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
- RStudio Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)
- Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
- Computer: macOS Ventura, Version 13.1

I have tried updated my macOS version, reinstalling R, and reinstalling R Studio.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641315/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit-at-r-startup

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but perhaps you need to 'clean up' your RStudio project environment? I.e. remove large objects/datasets/etc and free up memory?